# Memory card not detected in PC

Tags: windows, memory

I have a password protected Sandisk 2gb micro memory card. I have set a password protection for my memory card. Unfortunately I forgot the password which I have set for my memory card.

I have formatted my memory card. It didn't ask the password when I formated my memory card from my phone. After that format my memory card is not detecting on any mobiles and even my computer.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: As per Scandisk, this could be due to possible corruption in the registry entry. Please refer the steps detailed by them to fix the issue: http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/205/session/L3RpbWUvMTQxNjkzNTg5NS9zaWQvTjRSU1dqOG0%3D

Comment: What format did you format the disk as?

Comment: @RowlandShaw ntfs

Comment: What sort of devices specifically because NTFS is likely the reason its not working on "mobiles"

Comment: @Ramhound its not even working on windows

Comment: @vembutech i have tried the method you have suggested but it isnt working'

Answer (score -2):

Try using diskpart to wipe off the entire partition table.
Wiping partition will delete data in your memory card.

Ok so you shoukd first run diskpart by going to Start->run and type diskpart and hit return key

Now, type "list disk" (without quotes). This would show you all the disks detected by the OS (hard drives, flash drives etc.)

If you find more than one disk, then locate your memory card by using the size (capacity header) of the output.

Now type "select disk n" (where n is the disk number)

Now type clean and wait. It will wipe off the partition table

Now all you need to do is create a partition either by using the pc or chances are your phone would be able to do it ;)

Comment: How about be specfic on what command should be used

Comment: @Surya Teja Karra how can i use dikpart actually..my memorry card isnt detecting

Comment: see my memory card isnt detecting

Comment: you mean there was no other disk  rather than disk 0 in list disk output

Comment: @Surya Teja Karra see i have done the method you suggested ..when i run the diskpart and selects my disk and tried the command clean it shows me message like `virtual disk service error.There is no media in this device`